Proving inequality for CORDIC algorithm convergence in hyperbolic mode
In this paper which describes the generalized CORDIC algorithm, the author claims that for positive integers $n$, we have the inequality:
$$\sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i}) < \tanh^{-1}(2^{-n}) < \tanh^{-1}(2^{-(3n + 1)}) + \sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i})$$
However, the author does not prove this inequality, and every single paper I could find about the algorithm refers back to the original paper's claim. I'd like to understand why this inequality is true so that I can optimize the algorithm when I implement it.
I can prove the first part of the inequality using the Taylor expansion of $\tanh^{-1}$, but I can’t prove the second part with the $3n+1$.
How would I prove that second part of the inequality? What is so special about $3n+1$ in particular?

Ok I think I've found a proof.
First, we use the Taylor expansion $\tanh^{-1}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k - 1}}{2k - 1}$ to get the first part of the inequality:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i}) &= \sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-i(2k - 1)}}{2k - 1}\\[0.5em]
&= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-(n + 1)(2k - 1)} / (1 - 2^{-(2k - 1)})}{2k - 1}\\[0.5em]
&= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-n(2k - 1)}}{2k - 1} \cdot \frac{2^{-(2k - 1)}}{1 - 2^{-(2k - 1)}}\\[0.5em]
&< \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-n(2k - 1)}}{2k - 1}\\[0.5em]
&= \tanh^{-1}(2^{-n})
\end{align*}$$
Then for the second part:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i}) + \tanh^{-1}(2^{-(3n + 1)}) &> \sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty 2^{-i} + 2^{-(3n + 1)}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{-n} + 2^{-3n}\left(\frac{1}{3} + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-2k}}{2}\right)\\[0.5em]
&> \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{2^{-n(2k - 1)}}{2k - 1}\\[0.5em]
&= \tanh^{-1}(2^{-n})
\end{align*}$$
(Note that $3n + 1$ is the largest integer that satisfies this inequality.)
Putting it all together, we get the desired result:
$$\sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i}) < \tanh^{-1}(2^{-n}) < \sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty \tanh^{-1}(2^{-i}) + \tanh^{-1}(2^{-(3n + 1)})$$
